# Test not reading my handler

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a TriggerHandler class and also a Trigger Handler Test Class. Now my problem is my Trigger Handler Test Class is not Testing my TriggerHandler Class but instead test my Trigger class thus resulting to 0% code coverage.

Trigger Handler Method

```
    public class MatterTriggerHandler { 
public static void GEandMCevaluation(List<Matter__c> MatterList)
        {

            Set<String> countryMatter = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> GoogleEntity = new Set<String>();   




            //capture Current google entity and current matter country
            for(Matter__c mat : MatterList ){
                countryMatter.add(mat.Matter_Country_Countries__c);
                GoogleEntity.add(mat.Google_Entity__c);
            }

            //query the captured google_entity__c and current_matter_country__c
            List<Matter_Entity_Currency_Schedule__c> listofentitiycountrycurrencies = 
                [Select Functional_Currency__c FROM Matter_Entity_Currency_Schedule__c where Google_Entity__c IN : GoogleEntity
                 AND Country__r.Country_Name__c IN: countryMatter ];




            String[] functionalCurrencies;
            for(Matter__c mat : MatterList ){

                if(!listofentitiycountrycurrencies.isEmpty()){
                    for(Matter_Entity_Currency_Schedule__c mescs : listofentitiycountrycurrencies){
                        mat.Available_Currency__c = mescs.functional_currency__c;
                        mat.HasValidEntityAndCountry__c = FALSE;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    mat.Available_Currency__c = 'No Available Currency';
                    mat.HasValidEntityAndCountry__c = TRUE;
                }
            }
        }}
```

My Test Class

```
private class MatterTriggerHandlerTest {

static testMethod void GEandMCevaluation(){

  //Populate Google Entity Lookup
  Google_Entity__c ge = new Google_Entity__c();
  ge.Name = 'Google Cable Japan GK';
  insert ge;

  //Populate Country Territory Lookup
  Country_Territory__c ct = new Country_Territory__c();
  ct.Country_Name__c ='Ireland';
  insert ct;

  //Create Matter Entity Currency Schedule Data  
  Matter_Entity_Currency_Schedule__c ms = new Matter_Entity_Currency_Schedule__c();
  ms.Functional_Currency__c = 'ARS; AUD';
  ms.Google_Entity__c = ge.Id;
  ms.Country__c = ct.Id;

  insert ms;

  //Create Matter Record
  List<Matter__c> oldMatter = new List<Matter__c>();
    for(Matter__c m : oldMatter){  
  m.Name = 'Testing 1234';
  m.Account__c = 'Testing 12345';
  m.Status__c = 'New';
  m.Google_Entity__c = ge.Id;
  m.Matter_Region__c = 'NACE';
  m.Matter_Country_Countries__c = 'Ireland';
  m.Does_an_NDA_exist__c = 'Yes';
  m.Description__c = 'For Testing Purposes';

  oldMatter.add(m);      
    }
  Test.startTest();
  insert oldMatter;
  Test.stopTest();

  List<Matter__c> newMList = [Select Id, Available_Currency__c from Matter__c where Id IN : oldMatter];

    for(Matter__c newM : newMList){
        System.assertEquals('ARS; AUD', newM.Available_Currency__c);
    }

}
```

My Trigger Class

```
trigger MatterTrigger on Matter__c (before insert, before update, after update, before delete, after insert) {
MatterTriggerHandler newM = new 

MatterTriggerHandler();

  if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
      MatterTriggerHandler.setOtherRegions(Trigger.new);
      MatterTriggerHandler.GEandMCevaluation(Trigger.new);
      MatterTriggerHandler.eSigValidaiton(Trigger.new);
  } else if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isUpdate) {
      MatterTriggerHandler.setOtherRegions(Trigger.new);
      MatterTriggerHandler.GEandMCevaluation(Trigger.new);
      MatterTriggerHandler.eSigValidaiton(Trigger.new);
  } else if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isDelete) {
      MatterTriggerHandler.closeMatter(Trigger.Old);
  } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
      newM.onAfterInsert(Trigger.new);
  } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
  } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isDelete) {
  } else if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUndelete) {
  }


}
```

I just didn't post all my triggerHandler Methods cause It's too long. I just posted an example.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: 1. Does the trigger actually call the handler? 2. Does the test actually pass?

Comment: My trigger call the handler but it's in a different class. I just didn't post it cause it maybe too long and also when I try it in the APEX TEST EXECUTION it says "1/1 test method Passed" @AdrianLarson

Comment: I would suggest trying to make your code more modular. Focus on `Separation Of Concerns`.

Comment: Thats a trigger handler? Seems you just added more spaghetti to the spagetti

Comment: I already posted my TriggerClass. Actually my problem is my test class tests my TriggerClass instead of the TriggerHandllerMethods class. @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you aren't getting any coverage is because you aren't inserting any `Matter__c` records.

Let's step through some of your code to see how I reached this conclusion.

```
//Create Matter Record
List<Matter__c> oldMatter = new List<Matter__c>();
```

So far, so good. You've initialized a list of `Matter__c`. It should be noted that this line of code does not itself create any `Matter__c` records. Moving on...

```
for(Matter__c m : oldMatter){  
  m.Name = 'Testing 1234';
  m.Account__c = 'Testing 12345';
  m.Status__c = 'New';
  m.Google_Entity__c = ge.Id;
  m.Matter_Region__c = 'NACE';
  m.Matter_Country_Countries__c = 'Ireland';
  m.Does_an_NDA_exist__c = 'Yes';
  m.Description__c = 'For Testing Purposes';

  oldMatter.add(m);      
}
```

This looks ok at first glance, but let's take a closer look at the very start of the loop

```
for(Matter__c m : oldMatter){
```

Since you haven't done anything with `oldMatter` besides initializing it, this line effectively becomes

```
for(Matter__c m : new List<Matter__c>()){
```

You're telling the for loop to iterate over the records in `oldMatter`, all 0 of them.

When a for loop is given an empty collection to work on, the loop will simply be skipped. So `oldMatter` continues to have no data in it. Moving on...

```
Test.startTest();
insert oldMatter;
Test.stopTest();
```

`oldMatter` is still empty, when a DML call is performed on an empty list, Salesforce is smart enough to not waste resources. Your trigger never gets called, explaining why you're getting no coverage.

To fix this, you need to get some data into `oldMatter`. You could modify your for loop to be `for(Integer i = 0; i < 1; i++){`, but a loop for creating a single record doesn't make any sense.

Instead, I'd just replace that loop with the following

```
oldMatter.add(new Matter__c(
    Name = 'Testing 1234',
    Account__c = 'Testing 12345',
    Status__c = 'New',
    Google_Entity__c = ge.Id,
    Matter_Region__c = 'NACE',
    Matter_Country_Countries__c = 'Ireland',
    Does_an_NDA_exist__c = 'Yes',
    Description__c = 'For Testing Purposes'
));
```

Now, if `Matter__c`'s `Account__c` field is a lookup, you'll need to prepare and insert an `Account`, and then use the account's Id much like you're doing for the `Google_Entity__c` field.